# a series of form posts with django results in 403 error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-csrf

if the user clicks submits a form on the landing page it takes them to a another page (second page) but if the user then tries to login on the second page via another form post the user receives a 403 forbidden error.

landing page form works.
login form works fine.
but submitting landing page form then login form results in 403 CSRF verification failed.

The form on the first page returns:

```
render(request, 'page.html', context_var)
```

The form void of css looks like:

```
<form action="{% url 'url_test' %}" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="some_name" value="for_view_use">
{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" name="other_name" value="value">button</button>
</form>
```

The second form or the view which allows the user to login returns:

```
HttpResponse('success')
```

and the login form void of css is:

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<button type="submit">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

I am sure both these views return these values as I have tested them separately.

I have tried using `@csrf_protect` but that hasn't worked. I've checked and the token is present on the second page when loaded. I know it's something to do with the csrf token but I can't figure it out.

to me it looks as if the first form isn't returning an acceptable csrf token for the next page.

EDIT:
I did not solve the problem itself but I noticed the first request was just pulling data from the server so I changed it to a GET request and the bug stopped happening. This is not an answer in my opinion so I will leave this thread open in case someone else is having trouble with consecutive form POST requests with django.

Comment: Can you give the full code for both views? Also, can you give clear examples of what gives the wrong behaviour? Is it the login form or your form that gives the error, it is not very clear from your question?

Comment: @raphv unfortunately I am working for a company where I can't give too much code away nor do I have anyone to consult with who can provide me with assistance. I made an edit to try and clarify my explanation of the bug. I do have permission to make this post though.

Comment: Are you using a custom login form or Django's basic login form? Can you at least give the part of the template that generates the form where there is an error? It should look like `<form action="{% url '...' %} method="post">{% csrf_token %}{{form}}...`. If you can't give away code that easily look at [how to create a minimum, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's nearly impossible to help you without seeing the code that generates this issue.

Comment: @raphv updated with additional code. it's a custom form.